# Error: Flag --allowed-unsafe-sysctls has been deprecated

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I'm trying to execute on the node `kubelet --allowed-unsafe-sysctls   'net.core.somaxconn'`

but return `Flag --allowed-unsafe-sysctls has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.`

I also tried using PodSecurityPolicy, but it still doesn't work

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  name: sysctl-psp
spec:
  sysctls:
    - net.*
  seLinux:
    rule: RunAsAny
  supplementalGroups:
    rule: RunAsAny
  runAsUser:
    rule: RunAsAny
  fsGroup:
    rule: RunAsAny
```

I received the following error:
`forbidden sysctl: "net.core.somaxconn" not whitelisted`

yaml  detailed:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: sysctl-example
spec:
  securityContext:
    sysctls:
      - name: net.core.somaxconn
        value: "65535"
        unsafe: true
  containers:
    - image: tomcat
      name: tomcat
```

Answer (score 5):

As the error suggests, You need to start the Kubelet with the `--config` flag which sets the path of the Kubelet's config file. The Kubelet will then load its config from this file.

You can write the config file by yourself or generate it by [KubeletConfiguration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/#create-the-config-file) object.

Sample YAML:

```yaml
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeletConfiguration
allowedUnsafeSysctls:
- "net.core.somaxconn"
```

Follow this doc - [Set Kubelet parameters via a config file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/)