# How to change value for TCP_KEEP_ALIVE value in K8S Pod

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I setup a k8s cluster using microk8s. I wonder how to change the default TCP Keep
Alive Value in the Pod. When i apply the yaml file, it will give me allowedUnsafeSysctls error

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: input-adaptor-deployment
  namespace: mgr-ns
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: input-adaptor
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: input-adaptor
    spec:
     securityContext:
      sysctls:
       - name: net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl
         value: "45"
       - name: net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes
         value: "15"
       - name: net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time
         value: "120"
      containers:
        - name: input-adaptor
          image: registry.development.gitlab/food/input-adaptor
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: '16Mi'
              cpu: '100m'
            limits:
              memory: '80Mi'
              cpu: '500m'
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5003

      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry-credentials-gitlab
```

:

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable unsafe sysctl settings. See the docs here

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/

There is also some good information in this answer":

[Error: Flag --allowed-unsafe-sysctls has been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63610651/error-flag-allowed-unsafe-sysctls-has-been-deprecated)

Note, you basically need to configure k8s to allow unsafe sysctl settings ie by allowing them you understand the consequences.

Comment: Just curious, how to apply to microk8s environment?

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/#podsecuritypolicy) you need to enable unsafe sysctl settings to fix your error:

> Sysctls are grouped into safe and unsafe sysctls. In addition to
> proper namespacing, a safe sysctl must be properly isolated between
> pods on the same node. All safe sysctls are enabled by default.All
> unsafe sysctls are disabled by default and must be allowed manually by
> the cluster admin on a per-node basis. Pods with disabled unsafe
> sysctls will be scheduled, but will fail to launch.

The following examples demonstrate how to set operating system TCP keep-alive parameters with an interval value of one minute.

```
sudo /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=60 net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=60 net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=5
```

To ensure that the settings survive a reboot, add the settings to your `/etc/sysctl.conf` file.

Refer to [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/general-tips) for more information.

Comment: How to add the setting to k8s environment?

Comment: Do checkout the [link](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/) for more information on setting k8 environment